# Print to console/command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt, autoit

I want to write text to console/Windows command prompt in AutoIt. I made a test script as shown below:

```
Func Test()
   ConsoleWrite("Hello")
EndFunc

Test()
```

I saved the script as `test.au3`. When I run it, it does not print to console. I checked [`ConsoleWrite()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ConsoleWrite.htm); it should print to DOS console if it the script is compiled as a console application.

I compiled the script using Aut2Exe. It still does not print to console. How do I write to console in AutoIt?

Comment: Are you using SciTE4AutoIt3?

Comment: Matt is correct, when you run your script in SciTE you will have a Console output below.

Answer (score 9):

You can also add the following compiler switch to the top of your script:

```
#pragma compile(Console, True)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just compile your test.au3 like this:

```
%PathToAutoItVersion%\Aut2Exe\Aut2exe.exe /in test.au3 /out test.exe /console
```

And then you can Run `test.exe` and it will print out:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I write to console in AutoIt?

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `ConsoleWrite()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ConsoleWrite.htm) :

> The purpose for this function is to write to the STDOUT stream. … Scripts *compiled as Console applications* also have a STDOUT stream.

Save script as `.au3` file, then:

- press <kbd>F5</kbd> (Tools > Go) in editor. Console output will be displayed in the editor's lower pane:
  [image]
- or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (Tools > Compile), enable `Create CUI instead of GUI EXE.`, then click `Compile Script` and run the resulting executable.
- or add `#AutoIt3Wrapper_Change2CUI=Y` ([or](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/167266-pragma-compile-vs-autoit3wrapper-directives-various-problems/) `#pragma compile(Console, True)`) [to top of script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27663324/4157124), then press <kbd>F7</kbd> (Tools > Build) and run the resulting executable.
- or execute:
  `...\AutoIt3\Aut2Exe\Aut2exe.exe /in ...\script.au3 /out ...\script.exe /console`
  and run the resulting executable.

> I compiled the script using Aut2Exe. It still does not print to console.

For compiled scripts a console window is visible during runtime only. Example:

```
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Change2CUI=Y

Global Enum  $EXITCODE_OK
Global Const $g_sMsg   = 'Hello, World!' & @CRLF
Global Const $g_iDelay = 1000 * 10

Main()

Func Main()

    ConsoleWrite($g_sMsg)
    Sleep($g_iDelay)

    Exit $EXITCODE_OK
EndFunc
```

Related: [Console and graphical user interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077941/4157124).