# ConsoleWrite() to GUICtrl element

Tags: user-interface, console, window, autoit

How can I put `ConsoleWrite()` into `GUICtrlCreateEdit()`?

[image: Images]

```
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
$Form1 = GUICreate("Test", 257, 182, 192, 124)
GUISetFont(12, 400, 0, "Times New Roman")
$test = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 8, 40, 241, 90, $ES_AUTOVSCROLL)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
    EndSwitch
WEnd

ConsoleWrite('Text test')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `GUICtrlSetData()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetData.htm):

> Modifies the data for a control.

Example:

```
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

$Form1 = GUICreate("Test", 257, 182, 192, 124)
$test = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 8, 40, 241, 90, $ES_AUTOVSCROLL)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            GUICtrlSetData($test, 'Shutting down in 5 seconds ...')
            Sleep(5 * 1000)
            Exit
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

> How can I put `ConsoleWrite()` into `GUICtrlCreateEdit()`?

Example:

```
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

$Form1 = GUICreate("Test", 257, 182, 192, 124)
$test = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 8, 40, 241, 90, $ES_AUTOVSCROLL)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            ConsoleWriteGUI($test, 'Shutting down in 10 seconds ...' & @CRLF)
            Sleep(5 * 1000)
            ConsoleWriteGUI($test, '5 more seconds ...' & @CRLF)
            Sleep(5 * 1000)
            Exit
    EndSwitch
WEnd

Func ConsoleWriteGUI(Const ByRef $hConsole, Const $sTxt)
    Local Static $sContent = ''

    $sContent &= $sTxt
    GUICtrlSetData($hConsole, $sContent)

EndFunc
```